# too many SQL variables and NOT IN clause

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have a table with a collection of ids (sqlite Android), and a collection of ids I want to retain.

Then if toRetain = [1,2,3,4] I create an execute:

```
DELETE FROM my_items WHERE _id NOT IN (1,2,3,4);
```

But if the length of the items to retain is very high the SQL engine throws an exception: **"too many SQL variables"**. Since the clause is NOT IN I can't do it in smaller steps.

How can i solve it?

One solution I think is to insert all the ids in a temporal table and then execute:

```
DELETE FROM my_items WHERE _id NOT IN (SELECT_id FROM items_to_delete);
```

Is that solution correct and efficient??

Comment: How many ids are there in the database? Is selecting all and checking against your retain list in Java possible? Do you maybe already know all possible ids? If not, temporal table sounds good. Or a "RETAIN_FLAG" column that you turn on first, and then delete where retain_flag = 0.

Comment: Typically in the database there is not a lot of items, but exceptionally it can be big

Comment: As an FYI, I just ran into this issue and found that the upper bound is 999 as at 1,000 you will receive this error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think creating a temp table or table variable and then insert all the ids to be retained in that. Then delete from the main table by joining main table with this temp or table variables.

Here I suggest to create an index if you use temp table also use the inner join insted of NOT IN

Comment: I'm not sure if the `NOT IN (SELECT..` approach isn't faster than using joins since joining is a quite complex thing. [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN [STATEMENT]`](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) can maybe tell

Comment: Why do u feel join as a complex thing?

Comment: SQLite joins tables by building the cartesian product of tables and afterwards filters out the uninteresting rows. Joining two 1000 row tables results in a 1000x1000 rows intermediate table already. Then each of the 1M rows is checked if it is required in the output and you end up with your desired 100 rows or so. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html / http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html

Answer (score 1):

Android doesnt like it when you hardcode the values in the query, try

```
db.delete("my_items", "_id NOT IN (?, ?, ?, ?)", String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4"});
```

Or if you use ContentProvider, then:

```
getContentResolver().delete("content://uri/to/my/items", "_id NOT IN (?, ?, ?, ?)", String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I used the hardcore values only for the example but in the code I make it as you say

Comment: @Addev maybe hardcoding them would work, might be the case that the limit you observed applies to binding variables only